# Not parse the webservice

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

[This webservice](http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL)

i have this webservice. and i write below code for getting data from webservice. but not get data.

i tried this code.

```
 -(CGFloat)convertFrom:(NSString*)CountryName
    {

    NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetCitiesByCountry?CountryName=%@",CountryName];




        NSMutableURLRequest * req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [req setValue:@"http://www.webserviceX.NET" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
        [req setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

        NSData * data  = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:nil error:nil];

        NSLog(@"%@",data);

        xmlResultString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

        NSLog(@"%@",xmlResultString);

        parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:data];
        [parser setDelegate:self];
        [parser parse];
        return result;

    }
    - (IBAction)ParseTapped:(id)sender
    {
        //NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=%@&ToCurrency=%@",fromCurrency,toCurrency];

        [self convertFrom:@"India"];


        //return result;

    }

    -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
    {

        [xmlResultString appendString:[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]];

    }
    -(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
    {
        result = [xmlResultString floatValue];

        NSLog(@"%f",result);

    }

    -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
    {
        result = -1;
    }
```

**foundCharacters:(NSString *)string**

**(NSXMLParser *)parser**

this two method not being called.

but not get the data. where may i go wrong please help me out this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: NSData * data  = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:nil error:nil];NSLog(@"%@",data);So you are not even get the log data itself?

Comment: data get but found character method not called.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",data);(Inside convertFrom method) What it prints?

Comment: <3c21444f 43545950 45204854 4d4c2050 55424c49 4320222d 2f2f5733 432f2f44 54442048 544d4c20 342e3031 2f2f454e 22226874>   print like this...

Comment: when i look into your service it looks like a WSDL service. so use this like http://sudzc.com

Comment: Kiran i have solve this problem from couple of days...

Answer (score 0):

I think the URL parameter your passing is incorrect. When I tried your WS URL,

http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetCitiesByCountry?GetCitiesByCountryResult=India

It gives an error, **Missing parameter: CountryName**

[image]

The correct URL parameter seems to be **CountryName** and not **GetCitiesByCountryResult**. This modified URL gives XML result. Check in WSDL what parameters need to be passed for a particular WS.

http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetCitiesByCountry?CountryName=India

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for your reply now i change my url like this but still not work  url is  NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetCitiesByCountry?CountryName=%@",CountryName];

Comment: What is the error/log that you get when you say it does not work?

Comment: -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError  this method called not called found character method..

Comment: Can you print the `parseError` description and check what is the reason for failure?

Comment: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 65.)"  this error occured..

Comment: The error code is `NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 65` is [`NSXMLParserSpaceRequiredError`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001984-SW1) which means parser is expecting space at some place in the XML response. Check with the server side dev and ask him to modify the XML to resolve this issue.

Comment: check webservice proprly i am directly fetch that webservice how may i made chanf=ges into that..

Comment: @JitendraDeore It looks like formatting issue in the XML, which can be resolved from server side only. You should not modify response on client side.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this in your convertFrom method.

```
 NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body>
<GetCitiesByCountry xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
<CountryName>%@</CountryName>
</GetCitiesByCountry>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>",CountryName];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx];
        NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        NSString * msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

        [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [theRequest addValue: @"http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCitiesByCountry" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
        [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSData * data  = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```